# Как сохранить значение option при переходе на другую страницу

Tags: javascript, php, html

Имеется следующий код для сортировки:

```
<select name="category" onchange="if(this.value){window.location.href = this.value; }">
    <option value="<?=makeUrl('category','all')?>" selected="">Все объявления</option>
    <option value="<?=makeUrl('category','Строительство')?>" data-val="Строительство">Строительство</option>
    <option value="<?=makeUrl('category','Ремонт')?>" data-val="Ремонт">Ремонт</option>
    <option value="<?=makeUrl('category','Уборка')?>" data-val="Уборка">Уборка</option>
    <option value="<?=makeUrl('category','Подручный')?>" data-val="Подручный">Подручный</option>
</select>
```

После перехода по необходимой ссылки сбрасывается значение option, как я могу его сохранить, либо же выбрать option по get параметру?

Comment: в одну сторону `href = value` сделали, так сделайте теперь `value = href`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю такие варианты:

- Сохранять все значения в localstorage
- Сохранять все значения в cookie
- Передавать значения на следующую страницу через get или post параметры

Comment: У меня формируется запрос как раз по гет параметрам. Допустим я его извлек, а как мне отобразить его в моем select?

Comment: Решил вопрос. Беру значение из GET параметра и дальше просто вставляю его в один из option следующим образом:
<option value="" disabled="" selected=""><?=$category?></option>